# Is Para HP better than Para Def for 0/8 robe characters?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

I've been going through the learning phase 1 (surviving more than 20 hours on a level 20 character) and I started stacking pots in my vault, but as a 0/8 character I'm running with a para HP ring.

Now I recently found a Para Def ring and I know it's been rated better than Para HP, but is it a good idea to sacrifice 120HP for 8 def as a wizard/robe character (or a new player)?

Is it better for me to keep the Paramount Health ring or should I swap for the Paramount Defense ring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From the RealmEye Wiki:](https://www.realmeye.com/wiki/def-vs-hp-vs-vit)

> If you can only survive 17 hits or less, HP is better. If you can survive 18 hits or more, Def is better.

I'm going to assume you haven't drank any Potions of Life at 0/8.

All of the robe classes have an average HP of 575 at Level 20. 575 divided by 17 is about 33.8. If on average shots are 34 or larger, use an hp ring. If they are smaller, use a defense ring.

Don't go overkill on defense. Defense caps at reducing the damage of an attack at 85 percent. That means even if you have 100 def vs 200 def, they will both reduce an 100 damage attack to 15 damage.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the circumstances.

Some factors:

- Amount of monsters at the same time.
- Base monster damage. (Low dmg = defense.. high dmg = hp perhaps)
- Your current armor (on heavy armor extra defense (mind dmg reduction
  cap - else hp))
- How fast you can kill the target. ( not going to take hits or almost
  none.. hp for surviving accidental hits)

It depends on what you will be doing. 
When farming gods, I'd take hp over only 8 dmg reduction due to their heavy hits.

When farming lower mobs in higher quantities, defense may actually be better.. but remember there is a dmg reduction cap on the monsters base dmg.

Since you are stacking pots I assume gods+dungeons.
HP for gods and higher dungeons.
Defense for the rest.

It has been a while since I played so this may or may not be accurate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on running around in the Godlands, defense is better. Vitality heal is not based upon max hp so you don't heal faster with more hp, and you won't be max hp for long. HP ring has no effect if your health is less than base max. Defense ring works all the time.